# Converted code using Swift and got multiple errors (see image)

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Very new to coding and only learning Swift so far, in a course to make IOS apps that is not updated to IOS 9 and when trying to convert got these errors. I've resolved 2 but these are beyond my scope and I can't move forward.  Please help.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class NewSoundViewController: UIViewController {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        var baseString : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0]

        var pathComponents = [baseString, "MyAudio.m4a"]
        var audioNSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)
        var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        } catch _ {
        }

        var recordSettings: [NSObject : AnyObject] = Dictionary()
        recordSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC
        recordSettings[AVSampleRateKey] = 44100.0
        recordSettings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 2

        self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: (audioNSURL)!, settings: recordSettings)
        self.audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
        self.audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    }
```

[Error message in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8ZpE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that will actually compile:

```
class NewSoundViewController: UIViewController {

    private var audioRecorder : AVAudioRecorder?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        do {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        } catch _ {
            // TODO: actually handle the error.
        }

        let baseString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0]
        let pathComponents = [baseString, "MyAudio.m4a"]
        if let audioNSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents) {

            var recordSettings = [String : AnyObject]()
            recordSettings[AVFormatIDKey]         = Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)
            recordSettings[AVSampleRateKey]       = 44100.0
            recordSettings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 2

            // TODO: error handling
            let audioRecorder = try? AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioNSURL, settings: recordSettings)
            self.audioRecorder = audioRecorder
            self.audioRecorder?.meteringEnabled = true
            self.audioRecorder?.prepareToRecord()
        }

        // need to call super.init
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Note that I replaced almost all of the `var`s with `let`s. 
By default you should make all of your variables `let`, and only use `var` if you need to change the value later on.

There are some other stylistic changes that aren't necessarily better than the code you wrote, but an alternate way of writing swift (like using the dictionary literal syntax instead of the explicit constructor and using `try?` syntax).

Comment: Good call on the simpler Int() syntax over the explicit NSNumber creation, as that will get automatically converted to NSNumber and is cleaner looking.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wrap the unsigned int value kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC in an NSNumber to put it in that dictionary. `AnyObject` means the value must be an object. If it was `Any`, then it could hold the UInt32 value directly. So use this instead:

`recordSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)`

And your URL coming from NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents) is an optional, meaning it could be nil. The API requires a never nil value, i.e. one that is not optional.

If you're sure it will exist, you can use the following to implicitly unwrap it:

`self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioNSURL!, settings: recordSettings)`

or you could do something like this to be safer:

```
if let audioNSURL = audioNSURL {
    self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioNSURL, settings: recordSettings)
}
```

Comment: thanks @eintsteinx2 your solution for the 1st issue resolved the error.  However I tried both options you provided for the 2nd problem and I still get the same error 

"Cannot covert value of type [NSObject : AnyObject] to expected argument type [String : AnyObject]"

Comment: In that case you need to declare your dictionary as [String: AnyObject]. So instead of `var recordSettings: [NSObject : AnyObject] = Dictionary()` use `var recordSettings: [String: AnyObject] = Dictionary()` or even better `var recordSettings = [String: AnyObject]()`